Using Gradient Descent for coefficient estimation in ARMA model
I'm trying to implement an ARMA model from scratch using gradient descent with adam optimizer to estimate its coefficients . I know it might not be the ideal solution. But the thing that I'm mostly worry about is that if it is not a correct solution.
This is my ARMA model equation . For this, assume that dataset is already stationary.
$$
    \hat{Y}_n = \phi_1 Y_{n - 1} + \phi_2 Y_{n - 2} + \theta_1 \epsilon_{n - 1} + \theta_2 \epsilon_{n - 2} + \epsilon_n
$$
For this I took Residual sum of squares as follows,
$$
    \text{RSS} = \sum (Y - \hat{Y})^2
$$
and the derivatives as follows:
$$
    \begin{align*}
        \dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \phi_1} &= -2 \sum (Y - \hat{Y}) Y_{n - 1} \\
        \dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \phi_2} &= -2 \sum (Y - \hat{Y}) Y_{n - 2} \\
        \dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \theta_1} &= -2 \sum (Y - \hat{Y}) \epsilon_{n - 1}\\
        \dfrac{\partial \text{RSS}}{\partial \theta_2} &= -2 \sum (Y - \hat{Y}) \epsilon_{n - 2}
    \end{align*}
$$
Then using gradient descent algorithm, I can get values for all coefficients. Is this a good approach?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
